# How to determine obscure c types

Tags: c

Alright, this is a dumb question since I've been coding in C for a while but I've never really figured it out.

C libraries love to implement their own obscure data types which generally just seem to be reimplementations of existing types (the library prompting this question was http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gettimeofday.2.html).

My question is: how on earth are you supposed to figure out what these one-off datatypes actually are?  They never seem to be defined anywhere in the man pages, so short of digging deep into the source code of a header file I'm at a loss.  For example, from the above mentioned man page, what is a "suseconds_t" and how, in the general case, would I figure out what that is in detail?

Comment: General documentation cannot specify something that is implementation specific. You know that `sys/time.h` contains the struct: starting from there you should find the definition of type. Or documentation of your specific platform/sdk should describe type deeply.

Comment: You can [use search](https://www.google.fi/search?q=suseconds_t&sitesearch=man7.org/linux/man-pages&sa=Search+online+pages&gws_rd=cr&ei=VXgJWYj3Eomv6ASGrpH4Cw). From search results I selected [sys_types header which defines `suseconds_t`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man0/sys_types.h.0p.html).

Comment: Since you know it's in `sys/time.h`, you can do this: `echo '#include <sys/time.h>' >/tmp/chocofoo.c && c99 -E /tmp/chocofoo.c | egrep '[[:blank:]]+tv_usec' ; rm /tmp/chocofoo.c`; it might differ on some platforms as well, depending on whether you are compiling in 32-bit or 64-bit mode (or even X32 on x86_64 Linux platforms). In any case, my POSIX man page states that "`time_t` and `suseconds_t` types will be defined as described in `<sys/types.h>`. The POSIX man page for that header is linked in user694733's earlier comment.

Comment: Usually. grepping turns up the definition.

Comment: O/T: If you want to really go insane, look at [Windows data types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx). It's well structured, but it's that rigid structure coupled with specific types for specific use cases that drives me mad. It's easy to understand why WinForms, WPF, or whatever is shiny and new these days has become so much more popular on Windows than the Windows API itself. I'm grateful that POSIX requires so few data types in comparison!

Answer (score 2):

`suseconds_t` is a signed integer type that can fit the number of microseconds in a second. The type is `suseconds_t`, not anything else. The whole point of those "obscure" types is to make you use them instead of thinking "oh, I'll just use int because that's what I always use" and then your program becomes non-portable on some other machine or some time in the future.

Your slightly condescending tone in "C libraries love to..." is quite misguided. This is not some obscure library doing some obscure little funny thing. This is [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/sys/types.h.html#tag_13_67).

Comment: Arguably, POSIX is quite a bit on the obscure side. Especially since it hijacked the `_t` type naming convention that was industry standard long before POSIX existed. Basically the idea behind POSIX was "lets say that UNIX is standard and then show that standard down everyone's throat". That's not how you develop a successful industry standard.

Comment: Wasn't trying to be condescending.  I'm not saying the library is obscure, I'm saying the type suseconds_t is.  And I get that the reason is for abstraction, but for example I'm working on something where knowing the underlying type (signed int? unsigned int? long? short?) of suseconds_t would be useful, since I'd like to have some idea of the size of the type.  Yes, this will vary system to system, but I can make some guesses which in this case is all I need.  I can't find anywhere in the man-pages where this is specified; where would I look up this information?

Comment: Well, just being yesterday may, the fourth, just think on passing to the obscure side and think that types are some way of hidding internal structure to the external users of a type, and make it possible to think about microseconds in a portable way :)

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time you should code so that the underlying type is irrelevant.
That's the idea of portable, future-proofing code. On a different platform or in an upgrade types may change and existing code should just pick that up.

There are potential flaws though. For a scalar type like `susecond` as provided you may need to output it and the library should provide a `PRI`-style macro for output and a `SCN`-style macro for reading. See `<inttypes.h>`.
Otherwise you eventually have to come to concrete types.
These macros (or equivalent) are rarely defined (in my experience) and you have to deal with the implementation type at some point...

Also where not using generics (which are newish in C) and without C++ overloading you can hit trouble when passing values into other functions.
You call a function taking an `int` and then the library or platform changes and the underlying type of `susecond` is `long` and boom you've introduced a quiet truncation error! Always enable all your warnings!

Your IDE might let you hover over and look up the underlying type on the boundaries where you need it. But where possible just declare types to be `susecond` and let the compiler worry about it.

The reason it's done in this case is because (I guess) on 16-bit platforms `int` might not do for a value up to 999,999 (microseconds...) and this needs to be `long` but on 32-bit platforms where `int` is likely to be 32-bt it's fine.

16-bit? Are you sure Granddad? The library is not new and may well be portable to embedded systems where 16-bit is a perfectly reasonable thing to encounter.

Comment: I understand the abstraction, I'm mostly just wondering where I can actually look up the underlying data type.  Usually the abstraction is fine, but in this case I was hoping to figure out if the underlying type is long, short, int, etc.  While the exact size of those will also vary system to system, I'm working on something specific enough where just having a sense of the underlying type will be helpful.  Is there somewhere to look up the underlying type of things like susecond?  Because I can't find any reference to something like that in the man page.

Comment: @gmaster That depends on your coding environment. If you have a modern IDE you should just hover or right click the symbol in editing mode and it will offer options to see the definition or declaration. 
Otherwise it's searching in files to find that this is defined as that which is defined as something else which in a massive conditional compilation header is eventually defined as a concrete type. Good hunting!